# Who wants to spend some of my points on bounties?

Tags: discussion

The site limits a user to doing three at a time. Go ahead and suggest some unanswered questions for me that you think are good candidates. Perhaps some Q's that you think could do with a better answer that would benefit the whole community. ;)

(Ps. link to chat if you want to discuss any Q's... http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31431623#31431623)

Comment: Downvote? Being generous or trying to boost participation isn't wanted by everyone I suppose. Im actually willing to spend ALL my points... how's that.

Comment: Did you end up offering any bounties? I haven't seen the Featured tab on the questions list, so I guess not.

Comment: Not yet, but I will :) Also, thankyou for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this should be an answer of a comment, but if you're still offering:

- [What's wrong with my equity
  calculation?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/whats-wrong-with-my-equity-calculation) - Full disclosure, a question I posted myself today!
- [Can I fold my set here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/can-i-fold-my-set-here) - I plan on posting my own answer, but always interested to see other opinions.
- [Looking for mathematical paradoxes in Poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/looking-for-mathematical-paradoxes-in-poker) - I agree with your comment, some answers would be interesting.